# Retain and release nsstring

Tags: objective-c, release, retain

`str` is a NSString I own. It is my responsibility to release it, 
since I call `initWithString:`

```
if (![[str substringFromIndex:str.length-1] isEqualToString:@"\n"])
{
    str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
}
```

if the line inside the if statement reached, I will lose the ownership of the `str` var.

so my app crashes with a zombie instance, when I release `str` later:

```
[str release];
```

All goes fine if the if statement is NO(false).

What can I do to maintain the ownership of str?

Note that `str` could be very long I don't want to init another NSString

Comment: FYI - calling `stringByAppendingString:` does `init` a whole new string.

Comment: rly? :) but maybe old string get released before :)?

Comment: @rmaddy what do you suggest?

Comment: May I ask why you don't use ARC? It's 2015. Don't make your life harder unless you really have to.

Comment: this an old app. all implemented without arc. I did it years ago

Comment: *"what do you suggest?"* Use ARC. Xcode makes it easy to convert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do normal memory management:

```
if (![[str substringFromIndex:str.length-1] isEqualToString:@"\n"])
{
    NSString *newStr = [str stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
    [str release];
    str = [newStr retain];
}
```

Keep in mind that `stringByAppendingString:` returns an autoreleased string (and it also creates a whole new string).

Comment: isn't there anyway to add a new line to the str without creating a new srt

Comment: There's only one way - use an `NSMutableString`.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion 1: Use ARC. It solves these problems for you. This is by far the best solution.

As rmaddy says, Xcode has an automated tool for converting apps to ARC.  Look in the edit menu, under refactor>Convert to Objective-C ARC. The process is fairly painless. It flags things it wasn't able to figure out on it's own (usually only a few things.) After you clean up those issues you are off and running and never have to worry about retain counts again.

Suggestion 1a: Make str a mutable string, as @rmaddy suggested.

Then your code would look like this:

[str appendString: @"\n"];

That's simpler, easier to read, more memory-efficient, and works exactly the same in both ARC and manual reference counting.

Failing that, change str to be a retained property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *str);
```

Then use property notation:

```
if (![[self.str substringFromIndex: self.str.length-1] isEqualToString:@"\n"])
{
    self.str = [self.str stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
}
```

When you do that the setter for the property takes care of releasing the old object in the str property before assigning a new value to the property.

Be aware, though, that assigning an object to a retained property increases it's retain count. This will create a leak:

```
self.str = [NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"number %d", value];
```

(because all alloc/init calls return objects with a retain-count of 1)

and then the property retains it again.

That code should be written like this:

```
self.str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"number %d", value] autorelease];
```